# VR Convergence Plain Distance

Tags: camera

How is the Convergence Plain Distance set in Video-Games?

In Playstation VR or Oculus Go, everything looks great. But when I'm exporting Videos in Blender, I have to set something in to focus with the Convergence Plain Distance. Sadly, everything else is looking terrible. (If there is a great distance between Objects: lets say a Spaceship in Focus and the earth in background for example)  It makes you feel sick, and the eyes hurt.

What do they do in Video Games to make it all looking "normal" like in the real world?

Comment: Could you clarify please: You exported a stereoscopic video, view it with a VR headset and everything which is not on the convergence plane is 'looking terrible'? (1) Did I understand correctly? (2) Did you make sure that you are using an appropriate focal length? (3) Did you decrease the Interocular Distance to as low as possible?

Comment: If you habe a VR-Headset: My Problem is very good visible in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVCba6BFIwY

1: Yes, you understood correctly

2: There is no focal length in equirectangular mode. But the sensor width may has some influence. It's set to the default 36mm for now.

3: The Interocular Distance is set to the default 65mm - that's the average eye-distance, I guess, that should do well.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I'm honestly searching for some help with a lot of Experience. I'm working since about 3 Years with VR and experimented many times. Still not able to see what I should change here...  "Spherical Stereo" is allways the needed one when working in Equirectangular mode. "Parallel" is setting the cameras looking straight - got no idea for what that can be used. But it's not giving good results in VR.